# Password can't be blank, Bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt

After installing Bcrypt on my Rails app, there is a validation problem :password=>"Can't be blank", even though form is filled out:

This is my User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base   
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }   
  validates :username, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :email, presence:   true,
            format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }   
  has_secure_password   
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 } 
end
```

I've tried in the rails c and now the digest appears:

User.create:

```
User.create(username: "Riprova", email:"testato@gmail.com", password: "nonfunzia", password_confirmation:"nonfunzia")

<User id: 15, username: "Riprova", name: nil, surname: nil, email: "testato@gmail.com", gender: nil, birth: nil, created_at: "2013-08-11 15:35:03", updated_at: "2013-08-11 15:35:03", password_digest: "$2a$10$Q/5qtZYDXRcFsUWgve3JL.wui4hSHLhGgsuO0C6TTkBY...">
```

User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :name, :surname, :email, :bids_left, :bids_left_free, :gender, :birth)
    end
end
```

Comment: try removing the before_save just to see what happens?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the last statement "but didn't save anything".  Do you mean see anything?  What if you do a .create at the console?

Comment: `has_secure_password` will validate password presence by default, just fyi.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant i've added the User.create

Comment: Not sure if this is still a problem, but the `User.create` code you posted specifies a password with length of **5**, whereas your validation requires minimum length **6**. Have you tried `User.create` in the console with a longer password? And if so, what happens?

Comment: @user2062950 now the digest appears in the rails c but still doesn't work in the app. :(

Comment: Can you post the controller code?

Comment: Looks like you're missing `:password` and `:password_confirmation` from `user_params`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Rails 3.x you need to add `attr_accessible :password` or that parameter will be disallowed. On Rails 4, see [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html). The password param is probably being filtered out. Others (like username) probably as well.

Comment: Yes, the problem was in the user parameters(didn't included password and password confirmation), thank you.